Vercel CORS Error when trying to fetch from backend api also hosted on Vercel
I'm trying to fetch data from my API hosted on Vercel but it says CORS error.
I can fetch the data from insomnia and the same copy of the website locally works just fine. The same link gives the CORS error when the website went online.
I'm also using Vercel to host the website.
I'm using Reactjs for the website and Axios to fetch.
Using inspect element it shows strict-origin-when-cross-origin.

API vercel.json:
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/(.*)", // Assuming your API routes start with "/api/"
      "methods": ["GET", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "DELETE", "POST", "PUT"],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
      },
      "dest": "/index.js"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/index.js"
    }
  ]
}

Website vercel.json:
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}

Here is Backend API:
const express = require("express");
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
require("dotenv").config(); // Load environment variables from .env
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const allowCors = (fn) => async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
  );

  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.status(200).end();
    return;
  }

  return await fn(req, res);
};

const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI; // Use the MONGO_URI from .env

app.use(express.json());

app.get(
  "/api/chapters",
  allowCors(async (req, res) => {
    const client = new MongoClient(uri);

    try {
      await client.connect();
      const database = client.db("manhwa"); 
      const collection = database.collection("chapters"); 

      const chapters = await collection.find({}).toArray();

      if (chapters.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("No chapters found in the collection.");
      }

      res.status(200).json(chapters);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error fetching chapters:", e.message);
      res
        .status(500)
        .json({ error: "Failed to fetch data", details: e.message });
    } finally {
      await client.close();
    }
  })
);

app.get(
  "/",
  allowCors(async (req, res) => {
    res.send("You Shoulden't Be Here.");
  })
);

app.get(
  "/api/chapters/:chapter_id",
  allowCors(async (req, res) => {
    const client = new MongoClient(uri);

    try {
      await client.connect();
      const database = client.db("manhwa"); // Replace with your database name
      const collection = database.collection("chapterDetails"); // Replace with your collection name

      const chapter_id = req.params.chapter_id;
      const chapter = await collection.findOne({ chapter_id: chapter_id });

      if (!chapter) {
        res.status(404).json({ error: "Chapter not found" });
      } else {
        res.status(200).json(chapter);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error fetching chapter:", e.message);
      res
        .status(500)
        .json({ error: "Failed to fetch data", details: e.message });
    } finally {
      await client.close();
    }
  })
);

app.get(
  "/api/proxy",
  allowCors(async (req, res) => {
    const { url } = req.query;

    if (!url) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "No URL provided" });
    }

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: "arraybuffer" });

      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT"
      );
      res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization"
      );

      res.end(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error in proxy endpoint:", error);
      res
        .status(500)
        .json({ error: "Error fetching the URL", details: error.message });
    }
  })
);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});


I tried enabling CORS from API and the vercel.json, but it did not work.

Are you using Express in the backend?
By  this "I tried enabling cors from API..." did you mean that you tried CORs setup in your backend but it did not work? In that case would you please share that piece of code as well ?
And you may try removing the " {"src": "/(.*)" ..." }" from API vercel json as the CORS header will apply to all routes starts with /api.

Does this answer your question? How to enable CORS not working on vercel?

The Referrer Policy has nothing to do with CORS.
